# When I run "networksetup -getdnsservers airport" in Terminal, it says There aren't any DNS Servers set on Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, mac

When I run the networksetup -getdnsservers airport command in terminal, it says There aren't any DNS Servers set on Wi-Fi.

I need my primary DNS to fix my NAT Type on Xbox One.

Comment: DNS should be set in your router & relayed over wifi. The wifi should not be doing DHCP or NAT; you should leave those tasks to the router. Other than that, with so little information, it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Does the DNS server show in the Network part of System Preferences?

Comment: Yes but it's different from the DNS servers that show on my airport utility

Answer (score 2):

First run:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

Look for the `en0` or `en1` for your WiFi under the Device:

Then run:

```
ipconfig getpacket en0
```

Of course if your Wi-Fi is `en7`, then you need that instead of `en0` above. The broadcast DNS and search suffix are provided as output to the above `ifconfig getpacket` command towards the bottom of the options. If you don't get a packed in response to DHCP then you need to fix that on your network or log in to the router directly to retrieve the proper values.